# Can't add parameters to OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, oledbcommand

I have code like this:

```
using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} >= ? AND {2} <= ?",
            selectColumns,
            TableName,
            TimeStampColumn);

    var startTimeParam = command.CreateParameter();

    startTimeParam.ParameterName = "@StartTime";
    startTimeParam.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    startTimeParam.Value = StartDate;

    var endTimeParam = command.CreateParameter();
    endTimeParam.ParameterName = "@EndTime";
    endTimeParam.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    endTimeParam.Value = EndDate;

    DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(startTimeParam);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(endTimeParam);

    adapter.Fill(table);
}
```

But I'm unable to set the parameters for the select command. I tried use `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` in the instead of `?` but i got message `Must declare scalar variable @StartTime`.

When I'm using `?` instead of `@StartTime` or `@EndTime` i got no results.

It is working only when I put all variable in the `String.Format()` function, but i don't want to use is like this.

Comment: You should use `?` instead of `@StartTime` / `@EndTime`.  What error do you get when you use `?`?

Comment: What datatype are StartDate and EndDate? Where do you declare them and how do you initialize them?

Comment: @wdosanjos: should not matter anyway, even if you give them names only the order matters(because [OleDb doesn't support named parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407685/oledbparameters-and-parameter-names)). But that seems to be correct, because the StartTime-parameter is added before the EndTime-parameter.

Comment: Probably is something related to the Time part of those two parameters.

Comment: By the way `@StartDate` or `@StartTime` ???

Comment: @wdosanjos i tried using `?` but i got no results. Empty DataTable object.

@Steve both DateTime objects

Comment: I think it should be `OleDbType` instead of `DbType`.

Comment: One idea: maybe the start- and end-date are same and you expect that all records of this day are included. That's not the case if the record contains also the time. You have to use `AND {2} < ?` and `endTimeParam.Value = EndDate.Date.AddDays(1)` if you want to include the whole day.