# Trying To Make Update From Database GridView Specific User (OleDbCommand)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oledb, oledbcommand

Hey guys i am working about users GridView Database Upade, And i have a problem with my Update Row, Its telling me when i click on update, The Row is updated Succes but its not really updating it :(

Codes:

## 1 Asp.net(OleDB)

```
 protected void AdminBook_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE Users SET FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,UserPass=@UserPass,Gender=@Gender,Birthday=@Birthday,Email=@Email WHERE UserID=@id";
            OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPass", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserPass") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtGender") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBirthday") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(AdminBook.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            AdminBook.EditIndex = -1;
            PopulateGridView();
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "עריכת הנתונים התבצעה בהצלחה";
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
        lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

## 2 HTML (Very Short)

```
    <asp:GridView ID="AdminBook" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="UserID"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"

            OnRowCommand="AdminBook_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="AdminBook_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="AdminBook_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdating="AdminBook_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="AdminBook_RowDeleting"

            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" 
      BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
```

Picture that you can see it:
[Here you can see that it show the success message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HcRT.png)

Please help me... Because its making it succes but not really updating in database :(

Comment: `@UserName` parameter seems not assigned anywhere, can you confirm what kind of values stored inside `cmd.Parameters` array? Since you're using `OleDbCommand`, the parameter order matters rather than parameter name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem of your query is that the presence of this parameter definition:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
```

which doesn't exist in the query string, which has 7 parameters instead of 8 defined by `cmd.Parameters.Add()`:

```
UPDATE Users SET FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,UserPass=@UserPass,Gender=@Gender,Birthday=@Birthday,Email=@Email WHERE UserID=@id
```

Note that OLE DB doesn't recognize named parameters, it only recognizes [positional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21925885/) (query parameters are processed in their definition order instead). With current order in your code, the `UserName` parameter may be wrongly assigned as `id` and since provided value does not match with any values stored in `UserID` column, then no data is updated.

Hence, you should remove mentioned line above so that the query parameters matched exactly with their order present inside query string:

```
string query = "UPDATE Users SET FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,UserPass=@UserPass,Gender=@Gender,Birthday=@Birthday,Email=@Email WHERE UserID=@id";

OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, sqlCon);

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFirstName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtLastName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPass", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserPass") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtGender") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthday", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBirthday") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", (AdminBook.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmail") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(AdminBook.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
```

Or add `UserName` column before `WHERE` clause without changing parameter order:

```
string query = "UPDATE Users SET FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,UserPass=@UserPass,Gender=@Gender,Birthday=@Birthday,Email=@Email,
                UserName=@UserName WHERE UserID=@id";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Its helped me! Your answers are perfect! Well done! It was a big mistake and very stupid mistake from me :( Thank you very very much!

Comment: Alex i will be really happy if you help me with my new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599085/trying-to-make-search-database-by-username-in-textbox-by-paramaters-and-oledb