# Data type mismatch in criteria expression ms-access c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have `MS Access` database have table which contains below data.

```
    TradeDate   TradeType   TicketNo    PassengerName   
    11-Feb-19   SALE         1234       ABC
    12-Feb-19   PURCHASE     0345       XYZ
```

I want to get data between two dates with TradeType, below is my code from C#

```
public static DataTable GetSale(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate, string TradeType)
{    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();    
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Utility.GetConnectionString());
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT A.AgencyName, T.TradeDate, T.InvoiceNo, T.TicketNo, T.PassengerName, T.FatherName, T.TicketAmount, T.RefundAmount FROM Agencies AS A, Trade AS T WHERE T.Account_ID=A.Account_ID and T.TradeType=@TradeType And T.TradeDate>=@FromDate And T.TradeDate<@ToDate", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", FromDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", ToDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TradeType", TradeType);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
}
```

while executing my code

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Exception is thrown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are `FromDate`, `ToDate` and `TradeType`? Did you pass a string instead of a DateTime value perhaps? Finally, please don't use two-digit years. It's the most *in*famous bug in history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should know is parameters in `OleDbCommand` processed from order of their definition, you need to define parameters in same order as they're appeared in query ([OLE DB doesn't support named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407685/oledbparameters-and-parameter-names)).

Second, use `Add()` instead of `AddWithValue()` by specifying `OleDbType` for each parameter, you can see the list of types [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320435/info-oledbtype-enumeration-vs-microsoft-access-data-types).

Here is an example of correct setup:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Utility.GetConnectionString());
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT A.AgencyName, T.TradeDate, T.InvoiceNo, T.TicketNo, T.PassengerName, T.FatherName, T.TicketAmount, T.RefundAmount 
                                    FROM Agencies AS A, Trade AS T 
                                    WHERE T.Account_ID=A.Account_ID 
                                    and T.TradeType = @TradeType And T.TradeDate >= @FromDate And T.TradeDate < @ToDate", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TradeType", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TradeType;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = FromDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = ToDate;
```

Comment: The parameters have to be in the same order as the table in the Access Database.

Answer (score 2):

please use `...Parameters.Add(...)` instead of  `AddWithValue`.

Without explicitly providing the type as in `command.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.Int);`, it will try to implicitly convert the input to what it is expecting and it fails.