# MS Access DB INSERT Command with parameters in C# (invalid parameter)

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert

```
using OleDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
using OleDbCommand insertCommand = new() { Connection = connection, Transaction = transaction };
insertCommand.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_CARDS ([CODE], [EXPLAIN], [GROUP_CODE], [CUSTOMER_TYPE], [CREDIT_TYPE], [PAY_TYPE], [PAY_PARAM], [EXTRE_TIME], [LICENCE_DATE], [ADRESS1], [ADRESS2], [ADRESS3], [CITY], [ZIP_CODE], [PHONE1], [PHONE2], [FAX], [E_MAIL], [URL], [TAX_OFFICE], [TAX_NUMBER], [SS_NO], [MARRIAGE_DATE], [BIRTH_DAY], [BIT_FLAG_INT], [BANK_NO], [BANK_NAME], [CREDIT_LIMIT], [REAL_LIMIT], [DISCOUNT], [DISCOUNT_TYPE], [DISCOUNT_LIMIT], [USING_SELL_PRICE], [NOTES], [BASEBONUS], [EARNEDBONUS], [UPDATE_DATE], [UPDATE_WHO], [UPDATE_MODE]) VALUES (@ccode, @explain, '1', '1', '', 0, 1, 0, '2000-01-01', @address1, @address2, @address3, @city, '', @phone1, '', '', @email, '', @taxoffice, @taxnumber, '', '', '', 0, '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, @updateday, '', 0)";

insertCommand.Parameters.Clear();
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccode", musteri.MusteriVergiKimlikNo);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@explain", musteri.MusteriUnvan.Length > 30 ? musteri.MusteriUnvan.Substring(0, 30) : musteri.MusteriUnvan);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", musteri.MusteriAdres.Length > 30 ? musteri.MusteriAdres.Substring(0, 30) : musteri.MusteriAdres);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", musteri.MusteriAdres.Length > 30 ? musteri.MusteriAdres.Substring(30, Math.Min(30, musteri.MusteriAdres.Length - 30)) : "");
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address3", musteri.MusteriAdres.Length > 60 ? musteri.MusteriAdres.Substring(60, Math.Min(30, musteri.MusteriAdres.Length - 60)) : "");
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", musteri.MusteriSehir.Length > 20 ? musteri.MusteriSehir.Substring(0, 20) : musteri.MusteriSehir);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone1", musteri.MusteriTelefon.Length > 25 ? musteri.MusteriTelefon.Substring(0, 25) : musteri.MusteriTelefon);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", musteri.MusteriEmail.Length > 25 ? musteri.MusteriEmail.Substring(0, 25) : musteri.MusteriEmail);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taxoffice", "");
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taxnumber", musteri.MusteriVergiKimlikNo.Length > 12 ? musteri.MusteriVergiKimlikNo.Substring(0, 12) : musteri.MusteriVergiKimlikNo);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateday", $"{DateTime.Now.Year}-{DateTime.Now.Month}-{DateTime.Now.Day} 00:00:00");

await insertCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Exception :

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Invalid Parameter.'

When I adapt this code to VB.NET, it works, but with C#, it constantly gives a 'parameter error.' What am I missing? I tried the insert command with '?' as well, but the result didn't change. Can you please help?

Comment: AFAIK, OleDB parameterized query doesn't use parameters with the prefix `@` (named parameter). But using `?`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#remarks

Comment: I Try this command with parameter name "?" but error again..

Comment: Try to remove from the query text and from the values the "Licence_Date" part. I suppose that you cannot pass a date constant in that way to ms-access

Comment: Consider also that AddWithValue is a trap. Sometime it cannot create the parameters with the correct DataType expected by the database column. Use the more verbose, but more precise Add passing name, type, size and value

Comment: Programming is about taking what you already know and applying it to different situations. One thing you already know about problem-solving is to simplify the problem as a much as possible and then build it up piece by piece until it breaks. Start with zero parameters. If the command works, add one parameter. If that works, add one more. Keep doing that until it breaks. This is problem-solving 101 and not something specific to programming, so should not really need explaining.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407685/oledbparameters-and-parameter-names

Comment: Why are you using a `string` for the value of `UPDATE_DATE`? Please tell me that that column is type `Date/Time` and not `Text` or the like. If it is `Text`, that's a mistake in database design. If it is `Date/Time`, you should be passing a `DateTime` value. It looks to me like you should be using `DateTime.Today` as the value.

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters must be the same as the number of AddWithValue lines. The AddWithValue lines must be in the same order that values are passed in. And, as mentioned, use question marks [?] instead of field names in the CommandText.